# Using SockJS with Spring, with Websocket disabled

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket, sockjs

I need an help,
what I have to do is using Websocket with a client with "disabled websocket"

No problems while I try to use it without Oauth2 Authentication or with enabled websocket, I am in trouble when i try to do it with disabled ws && oauth2auth.

```
            var accessToken = oauth.getAccessToken();
            var socket = new SockJS("/ws?access_token=" + accessToken);
            self.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);


            self.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame)
            {
                console.log("Connecteded");...
```

`ws/info?access_token=..` goes well

`ws/1234/abc/xhr_streaming?access_token=..` goes well too

`ws/1234/abc/xhr_send?access_token=..` throws a 404 not found error(this one goes well when I don't add access_token in the url, but, ofc, i'm not authorized, cause i'm not identified, for using others services)

This is my Spring Configuration

ResourceServerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()

            // Resources
            .antMatchers("/favicon.png", "/favicon.ico", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/libs/**", "/templates/**", "/fonts/**", "/sounds/**", "/docs/**", "/ws/**").permitAll()
            // Pages
            .antMatchers("/", "/admin").permitAll()

            // Public APIs
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/users/search/emailExists").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/users/search/nicknameExists").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/users/passwordreset/request/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/users/passwordreset/reset").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/users").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/analytics/pageviews").permitAll()

            // Everything else
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

websocketmessageBroker

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/notifications");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry)
    {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS()
                .setSessionCookieNeeded(false);
    }
}
```

MvcConfig

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Bean
    public RequestParamsResolver requestParamsResolver()
    {
        return new RequestParamsResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers)
    {
        argumentResolvers.add(requestParamsResolver());

        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer)
    {
        configurer.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }
```

and websocketSecurity

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class WebsocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {

        messages                   
                .simpTypeMatchers(SimpMessageType.CONNECT, SimpMessageType.HEARTBEAT, SimpMessageType.UNSUBSCRIBE, SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT).permitAll()       
                .simpDestMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                .simpDestMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
                // catch all
                .anyMessage().denyAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        //disable CSRF for websockets for now...
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring websockets SockJS fallback protocols are not working out of the box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941610/spring-websockets-sockjs-fallback-protocols-are-not-working-out-of-the-box)