# Spring websockets SockJS fallback protocols are not working out of the box?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

I've made an app with `spring boot` with websockets support. Everything is
working great. I'm using `SockJS` + `Stomp`. No worries. It's just working. But
now I want to support the ability of `SockJS` use its fallback protocols. And
it seems that it's not working out of the box.

Here's how I added the endpoint:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
}
```

And that's it. No more configuraion.

And now when I disable webcokets in the brower and try to launch my app I get
`404` for the transport that the `SockJS` is trying to use as the fallback.

[image: 404 on SockJS fallback protocols]

See? First `GET /ws/iframe.html` 404 then `POST /ws/**/xhr_send?t=...` also 404.
What does this mean? Do I have to develop something else so that `SockJS`
fallback protocols will work?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this issue?

Comment: @fynn no :( still want the solution.. It's interesting to know that I'm not alone on this

Comment: Any Progress on this?

Answer (score 2):

xhr_send endpoint returns 404 if session id is not found.

If your Websocket service is scaled to multiple instances, root cause can be that session was initiated with one instance, and other instances are not aware about it.

Possible fixes:

- sticky sessions - route all requests from a client to the same instance
- distributed state - share user sessions between instances

Comment: It's just one instance of spring webapp. Nothing complex.

Comment: I found one interesting thing, that spring is searching for the "jsessionid" even if the session cookie is renamed via application.properties and therfore rejects all xhr calls of fallback strategies. See "org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportType" (Spring Boot 2.2.2).

Schould this be reported as a bug?

Comment: @zakjan i have facing this issue with a multi instance solution, do you have any example of how i can distribute state?  i tried to use spring-session but i am still getting the same issue.